# IIS Manager in Windows 11 not showing any site and IIS Admin not in services

Tags: windows, iis

I'm running a fresh installation of Windows 11, most IIS features are enabled, and IIS Manager doesn't show any site or the web server. Internet Information Services is not on the services list.

- IIS Manager and IIS Version (10.0)

[image]

- Services list

[image]
[image]

- Features on:

[image]

- iisreset /status

```
   Status for Windows Process Activation Service ( WAS ) : Running 

   Status for World Wide Web Publishing Service ( W3SVC ) : Running
```

What I've tried:

- Disable and reenable features
- Check for corrupted files following [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e There](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e%C2%A0There) were none.
- Did the above three times
- In the Event Viewer, there are no errors in Windows, but there is something in Custom Views / Server roles / Web Server:

```
    Log Name:      System Source:        Microsoft-Windows-IIS-APPHOSTSVC 
Date:          22/02/2023 14:44:53 Event ID:      9000 
Task Category: None Level:         Error Keywords:      
Classic User:          N/A Computer:      Desktop      
Description: The Application Host Helper Service encountered an error while reading the data for SID mapping.  Please ensure that the application pool name data is correct in the configuration file.  To resolve this issue, please recommit the changes or restart this service.  The data field contains the error number. Event Xml: http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">             9000     0     2     0     0     0x80000000000000          8182               System     
Desktop                02000780
```

I restarted the service Application Host Helper with no effect

Comment: Your image links are broken. Please use StackOverflow's own image-hosting instead of third-party links.

Comment: _"IIS Manager doesn't show any site or the web server"_ - did you try creating a website first? Did you launch IIS Manager with elevated/admin permissions?

Comment: _"Internet Information Services is not on the services list."_ - correct, because the service's display name is "World Wide Web Publishing Service".

Comment: Also, when troubleshooting IIS installs/configs, it helps to select **all** IIS features/options, including the IIS6 Metabase Compatibility and legacy administration services, as even in 2023 there's still a lot of Microsoft first-party web tooling that depends on those services and features.

Comment: Hi @Dai, I updated the images. Yes, IIS Manager launcher as Admin. There is no server visible. I added all features and rebooted

Comment: Also tried to enable with Powershell. Running url-rewrite https://tecadmin.net/enable-url-rewrite-iis/ gives an error `The IIS 7.0 CoreWebEngine and W3SVC features must be installed to use IIS URL Rewrite Module 2.`

Comment: The installation seems to be corrupt so you will have to verify and see whether it can be fixed, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/installation-issues/troubleshooting-iis-7x-installation-issues In worst cases you need to reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was given in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1183349/iis-manager-windows-11-not-showing-any-site

**Malwarebytes** prevents IIS from installing. To solve the issue: disable Malwarebytes, disable all IIS features, reboot, ensure Malwarebytes is still disabled, enable IIS features.